# Proving an identity about Catalan numbers

Tags: co.combinatorics, combinatorial-identities, catalan-numbers

$$C_{n} = \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i-1} \binom{n-i+1}{i} C_{n-i}$$

Are there any good combinatorial proofs or algebraic proofs of this?

Comment: Obvious comment: looks like some kind of inclusion-exclusion...

Comment: I rolled back your edit; you asked for a proof and received a proof; please don't change the question afterwards.

Comment: This is not research level.  It is more appropriate for https://math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I have a generalized version of this identity for the classic Fuss-Catalan numbers at my mini-arXiv ; "A Catalan Identity Related to Fibonacci Polynomials and Its Generalization to the Fuss-Catalan Number Sequences". It notes an article by Doslic
that contains a combinatorial proof for a more general identity that encompasses this Catalan identity. (https://tcjpn.wordpress.com/2023/05/31/a-catalan-identity-related-to-fibonacci-polynomials-and-its-generalization-to-the-fuss-catalan-number-sequences/). This replaces my May 12 answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

$C_n$ is the number of *Catalan sequences* $(x_1,\ldots,x_{2n})$ of $\pm 1$ with zero sum and non-negative prefix sums $x_1+\ldots+x_k$, for $k=1,\ldots,2n$. Note that any such sequence contains an index $j\in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ for which $x_j=1$, $x_{j+1}=-1$. Call $(j,j+1)$ a special pair. Then ${n-i+1\choose i}$ is the number of ways to choose $i$ special pairs (they are of course disjoint), and $C_{n-i}$ is the number of Catalan sequences with these $i$ pairs being special. Then your identity is just inclusion-exclusion. Note that the same argument shows that $$C_n=\sum_i (-1)^{i-1}{n+1+t-i\choose i}C_{n-i}$$
for every $t=0,1,\ldots,n-1$, if we consider special pairs with $j\in \{1,2,\ldots,n+t\}$.

Comment: Could you explain why there are nCr (−+1, i) number of ways to choose 
 special pairs?

Comment: @banana Consider the $i$ pairs $j,j+1$ as $i$ boxes (which may includes $n+1$ as well). Now put the remaining $n-2i+1$ numbers can be arranged in $i+1$ ( the places in between the boxes and on the sides) in $\binom{n-i+1}{i}$ ways.

Comment: if $j_1<j_2<\ldots<j_i$ are first elements of $i$ special pairs, then $j_1<j_2-1<j_3-2<\ldots <j_i-i+1\leqslant n-i+1$ are distinct numbers between 1 and $n-i+1$

Answer (score 21):

Algebraically, this identity is
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty C(n) x^n (1-x)^{n+1} = 1, $$
which is a consequence of the generating function
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty C(n) x^n = \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}.$$